# Get current ggplot object

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose I plot something like this:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Petal.Length)) + geom_point()
```

Then I realise that I forgot to store the result (i.e. the ggplot object).

**How can I retrieve the ggplot object corresponding to the current device?**

Is there some `ggplot` function I can feed `cur.dev()` into to retrieve the associated plot object, or is it gone forever?

(Note - in this case I could do `p <- .Last.value`, but let's assume I've typed a few commands since then so that this is not available.

Motivation - adding a hook to `knitr` to automagically set `fig.cap` to the title of the plot (if any)).

Comment: If your aim is to get a hook for `knitr`, I don't think you want to think so much of `cur.dev` but look at how `knitr` records plots using `evaluate`

Comment: I managed to get it working - using a combination of options `eval.after='fig.cap'` with `fig.cap=cap()`, where the `cap` function retrieves the title of the last plot (if any). hooks ended up not working because if you modify a chunk option in a hook it won't take effect until the next chunk.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are after [`last_plot`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/last_plot.html)

It retrieves  the last plot to be modified or created and is used by `ggsave`

Note that it is the last plot *modified* **or** *created*

`set_last_plot`  is the relevant code (see the [source](https://github.com/search?q=set_last_plot+%40hadley%2Fggplot2&type=Code))

It is important note that creating modifying or rendering a ggplot object will set the last plot.

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Petal.Length)) + geom_point()
f <- last_plot()
# will return the iris plot
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + geom_point()
last_plot()
# will return p
f
last_plot() 
# is now f
```

It will also not count any modifications / manipulation using `grid` or `gridExtra` (such as `grid.arrange` / `grid.text`

Comment: aha cheers, I knew there had to be a function, just didn't know what it was called!

Comment: A further question - is there a way to tell whether `last_plot` is the *current* plot? e.g. if I `ggplot(...)` and *then* `graphics.off()` or `plot(...)`, `last_plot()` still returns the last ggplot. Is there some way to check whether the returned plot was actually showing at the time of function call?

Comment: `ggplot2` stores the last plot, so you will be getting the last plot created by `ggplot` (ignoring any `grid` / viewport manipulations)

Comment: if you want the latest ggplot actually registered on the display list (and any further grid annotations), you could use `grid.grab`

Answer (score 1):

The last object assigned (and it does not need to be a plot object) can be recovered with `.Last.value`

```
>require(ggplot2)
#Loading required package: ggplot2
 ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Petal.Length)) + geom_point()
 gp <- .Last.value
 gp
```

This should return plot objects that have been modified by grid functions as long as there was an assignment. I'm not sure it this is true for actions that were mediated through `print` calls.